# Mistake in ProofWiki: Injection has Surjective Left Inverse Mapping?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The [first line of Proof 1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_has_Surjective_Left_Inverse_Mapping) states, "Since S is non-empty, we can choose an element $x\in S$."

Did the author mistakenly leave out the fact that S is non-empty in his/her statement of the theorem?

**EDIT 1**

Theorem: Let $f:S\to T$ be a injection. Then there is a surjection $g:T\to S$ such that $g\circ f=I_S$.

**EDIT 2**

Looks like I can get away with: Let $f:S\to T$ be a injection for $S\ne\emptyset$...

**FOLLOW-UP**

Here is my [formal proof](http://dcproof.com/CountableL4.htm) of the modified theorem (in DC Proof 2.0 format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case that $T\neq\emptyset$ there are no functions 
$$
f:\, T\to\emptyset
$$

since if $t\in T$ we can't map $T$ to an element of $\emptyset$.

So if such a function is defined there are elements in $S$.

But - There is a case that is missing, the case that $T=S=\emptyset$

Comment: Or should you fix up the statement of the theorem to avoid any functions potentially mapping a non-empty set to an empty set. How best to do that? I guess it only matters when there are mappings in both directions between 2 sets as here: $f: S\to T$ and $g:T\to S$. Either they are both empty or they are both non-empty? How about $S=\emptyset\iff T=\emptyset$?

Comment: It looks like I will only have to apply this theorem as a lemma for non-empty $S$ and $T$. Whew!

Comment: @DanChristensen- You don't have to fix the statement of the theorem for this case since it still holds for the empty function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function

Answer (score 0):

The statement of the result has now been amended to exclude the case where $S = \varnothing$.